# When Creating a InfluxDB Docker Container, how do I set the retention policy to store data for 30 days and in shards of 1 day

Tags: docker, docker-compose, influxdb

I am creating a docker container via docker-compose. using the following:

```
   influxdb:
     container_name: influxdb
     image: influxdb:latest
     restart: always
     ports:
       - "8086:8086"
     environment:
       INFLUXDB_DB: "databasenew"
       INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER: "admin"
       INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD: "admin"
       INFLUXDB_READ_USER: "user"
       INFLUXDB_READ_USER_PASSWORD: "user"
     volumes:
       - influxdb:/var/lib/influxdb
```

How can I create a retention policy that keeps data for 30days in 1 day shards. I want to be able to automate this for when I create the container via docker-compose. I do not want to have to use the CLI once the container is created.

Answer (score 0):

The most native option: https://hub.docker.com/_/influxdb

> The InfluxDB image contains some extra functionality for initializing a database. These options are not suggested for production, but are quite useful when running standalone instances for testing.
>   If the Docker image finds any files with the extensions .sh or .iql inside of the /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d folder, it will execute them. The order they are executed in is determined by the shell. This is usually alphabetical order.

So "code it" in .sh or .iql file and use volume. Of course you can also build own solution - e.g. create own image, ...